# Wifi stopped working on Arch on Macbook Air after system update

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, networkmanager, macintosh

After an Arch system update today, my wifi stopped working.  This is on a Macbook Air 2012.

```
% nmcli                                                                                                                                                                 ~
lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

Use "nmcli device show" to get complete information about known devices and
"nmcli connection show" to get an overview on active connection profiles.

Consult nmcli(1) and nmcli-examples(5) manual pages for complete usage details.
% nmcli con up id guybrush                                                                                                                                                ~
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.
%                                                                                                                                                                     4 ~
```

What do I do?  I use the broadcom-wl-dkms driver.

PS:

```
% sudo pacman -S  broadcom-wl-dkms                                                                                                                                      ~
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) broadcom-wl-dkms-6.30.223.271-17

Total Installed Size:   7.60 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      -0.02 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                                                         [############################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                                                                       [############################################################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                                                            [############################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                                                                      [############################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space                                                                    [############################################################] 100%
:: Running pre-transaction hooks...
(1/1) Remove DKMS modules
==> dkms remove broadcom-wl/6.30.223.271 -k 4.15.1-2-ARCH
Error! There is no instance of broadcom-wl 6.30.223.271
for kernel 4.15.1-2-ARCH (x86_64) located in the DKMS tree.
==> dkms remove broadcom-wl/6.30.223.271 -k 4.7.5-1-ARCH
Error! There is no instance of broadcom-wl 6.30.223.271
for kernel 4.7.5-1-ARCH (x86_64) located in the DKMS tree.
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) upgrading broadcom-wl-dkms                                                                       [############################################################] 100%

To load the new module, run the following commands as root:

  rmmod b43 b43legacy bcm43xx bcma brcm80211 brcmfmac brcmsmac ssb wl
  modprobe wl

Or just reboot the system.

:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/2) Install DKMS modules
==> dkms install broadcom-wl/6.30.223.271 -k 4.15.1-2-ARCH
==> dkms install broadcom-wl/6.30.223.271 -k 4.7.5-1-ARCH
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.7.5-1-ARCH (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/broadcom-wl/6.30.223.271/build/make.log for more information.
(2/2) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
%
```

Comment: Did the dmks module for your wifi driver get built correctly during update?

Comment: @Mioriin, it doesn't look that way; error messages above.

Answer (score 1):

I also have a Macbook with arch installed. I don't have it here, so I can't give a precise answer, but what I usually try in these cases is to revert to a previous version of the package:

```
cd /var/cache/pacman/pkg
sudo pacman -U broadcom-wl-dkms-VERSION
```

If you installed the driver through the AUR, it might be out of date, and in that case reinstalling might fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I see there's a new version from Jan 30, but after downgrading I still have the problem.

Comment: Maybe try rebooting after downgrading?

Comment: Tried that too.

Answer (score 1):

Installing `b43-firmware` from the AUR solved the problem.  No need to downgrade the driver.